# returns blank output for the page sing xpath to extract

Tags: xpath

i am trying to extract facts part from the page...but i get blank output for the page. i think its not entering the foreach loop since its not finding the nodes at all as i trid echoing "entered" inside the foreach but it never echoes.

```
    $my_url="http://a-z-animals.com/animals/affenpinscher-dog/";    
    $myhtml = file_get_contents($my_url); 
    $my_doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $my_doc->loadHTML($myhtml);

    $my_xpath = new DOMXPath($my_doc);
    $my_nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//*[@class="article_facts"]/tbody/tr' );     

    foreach( $my_nodes as $my_node )
    {           
    $title=$my_xpath->query('td[1]/b/a', $my_node)->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    $content=$my_xpath->query('td[2]', $my_node)->item(0)->nodeValue;       
    echo $title.",".$content."<br>";    
    }
```

Comment: why do you need 'tbody' in your xpath before the foreach?

Comment: then what should it be?

Comment: I think 'tbody' should be removed.